# CASE Statement in codeigniter query

Tags: php, sql

I have following table of students

Attendance is of the month of `November 2011`

```
    date       absentperiod         name         

    2011-11-01      1               x        
    2011-11-01      5               x        
    2011-11-01      5               y        
    2011-11-01      1               z
```

How to write `sql` query to find status? I am doing it in php.

I want to get output for employee `x - absent`, `y - half day`, `z- half day`

Students absent in period 1 and 5 should be absent
Students absent in period 1 or 5 should be HALF DAY

Comment: present, present  - should be present right?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select date,
  first_period,
  fifth_period,
  name,
  case when first_period != fifth_period 
  then 'Half day' 
  else first_period end status
from my_table;
```